# How do i pass a formated React Component Props?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

Can someone please tell me a way to solve this? Thanks in advance!

I have a component that receives a string value as a props.

What I want to do is:

Pass a formatted string into the props.

Ex:

```
<Component 
String ={
  `<p>Some text...</p>
   <p>Another text</p>`
}
/>
```

I have tried to passing the value to a const like:

```
const value =   `<p>Some text...</p>
   <p>Another text</p>`

<Component String={value} />
```

And the output would be the same:

`<p>Some text...</p> <p>Another text</p>`

Without being formatting the HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you are asking about how to render html coning from the props inside React component. In order to do that, you have to use ‘dangerouslySetInnerHTML’.

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using ‘innerHTML’ in the browser DOM. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out ‘dangerouslySetInnerHTML’ and pass an object with a ‘__html’ key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous. For example:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: “<p>Hello!</p>”}} />;
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to pass a string containing HTML tags to a component and for that component to print the string out as is, without formatting it as HTML. What you're doing is already correct, just render it and it will work:

```
const Component = ({String}) => {
  return (
    <div>{String}</div>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const value = `<p>Some text...</p>
   <p>Another text</p>`
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component String={value} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In case you actually want format it as HTML,  then this is what you need:

```
const Component = ({ String }) => {
  return <div>{String}</div>;
};

const Component1 = ({ String }) => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: String }} />;
};

export default function App() {
  const value = `<p>Some text...</p>
   <p>Another text</p>`;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component String={value} />
      <br />
      <Component1 String={value} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Component1` will format it for you.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-currying-v9srx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I think, OP wants to know about opposite: how to render html from the prop.

Comment: @DimaVishnyakov Perhaps. So I added a way to do that also.

Comment: Thank you, it worked exactly as i wished!